# getting error when saving entity inside an iterator

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am simply adding student to database by iterating through collection of type list `(i.e. Items)`. Items is not strongly typed here. I am getting this from somewhere else. So i need to construct Student object from it before writing it to SQL. It has student information.

It works fine for me as long as all fields validation okay.

However, if first item in the list has validation error `(i.e. Age required field in Student model)`, i get error which is fine. But for the second item i have valid Age value but still getting validation error for previous item.

```
try
{
     foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        Student student = new Student
        {
            StudentId = item.Id,
            Age = item.Age,
            Description = item.Description
        };

        _context.Student.Add(student);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}    
catch (MyCustomValidationException ex)
{
   //// catch it and log it
}
```

Is it something related the first item still attached to context?
How do i get rid of that? All i want to save items in DB by iterating through list whichever pass validation.

Items

```
public class Items
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Age {get; set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

This is how it is populated

```
items.Add(
new Items 
{
 new Items {Id = 1, Age = null, Description = "ABC"},
 new Items {Id = 1, Age = 12, Description = "ABC"}
}
)
```

Comment: What is in `Items`? What is the error?

Comment: Items as i said is 'Collection of type list'. It has student information. Error. Age is require field in my model. If Age is null in first iteration, i get validation error which is fine. But for second iteration i do have Age but EF still keeps on saying Age require.

Comment: could you post the code for _context class as well? BTW you normally use _context.Students instead of .Student, indicating that it is a set (which means records)

Comment: I wonder why this question has -ve !! it is fair question. It is tricky to understand for new comers how to work with context? When it gets dirty? Does EF auto wipe out dirty context or programmer has to do it? so i wonder why negative !! Can we have justification why it get negative? Secondly @doctor attitude is totally unacceptable... You asked for something and when get answer you just replied Please read !!! its ok not to answer rather then discouraging someone to ask. cheers.

Comment: I have downvoted because the OP does not provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest him to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (See **Help others reproduce the problem** section) because we are not magicians to predict data or the code we have not seen. @immirza btw `dotctor` not `doctor`. ;)

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without knowing **What is in `Items`**!

Comment: I literally don't see any need of seeing details of Items. @simbada explained quite well. He is new comer and couldn't understand how context gets dirty and when it comes back to normal state so he can add new item to DB. Maksim picked it up quite well. cheers

Comment: It is obvious that you are in contact with simbada because you know the content of deleted comments after they have deleted. @immirza. I'm out of this conversation because it does not help anyone.

Comment: fair enough. You still couldn't justify why you need Items. period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a required field `Age` in `Student`but you are providing a `null` value for it and it fails to insert in database.

You should validate the data you want to insert to database.

```
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    Student student = new Student
    {
        StudentId = item.Id,
        Age = item.Age,
        Description = item.Description
    };

    if (student.IsValid())
    {
        _context.Student.Add(student);
    } // else do something with invalid data! maybe warn user or log it ...
}
_context.SaveChanges();
```

add `IsValid` to `Student` class

```
public bool IsValid()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Age))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

What happens??

You add an invalid `Student` to context by calling `_context.Student.Add(student);`. Every time you call `_context.SaveChanges();` it tries to insert added `Student`s to database. You get the error until you remove invalid `Student`. It is not a good idea to call `SaveChanges` because it will hit the database every time you call it and it adds extra overhead. However if you want to check the validity one by one by calling `SaveChanges()` and get exception you can try this.

```
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    Student student = new Student
    {
        StudentId = item.Id,
        Age = item.Age,
        Description = item.Description
    };

    _context.Student.Add(student);

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (MyCustomValidationException ex)
    {
        _context.Student.Remove(student);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't save changes inside your loop, it will cause multiple insert queries to the database instead of one.

Secondly I believe your code is incomplete, since validation exception will be thrown and you will be out of your `foreach` loop. But even if you have a try/catch around your `_context.SaveChanges()` it doesn't cancel the fact that you still have invalid data in your context and calling `_context.SaveChanges()` second time will try to commit these changes for `Student` table again. It's not clear from your question, but I assume you have DB-side validation for Student's age.

Comment: You are exactly getting my problem. I do have Try Catch around around saveChanges. It catch validation error but when return back to second iteration it still complain for validation error. So what is the solution? How should i solve it?

Comment: The solution would be not to add invalid models into your context, add a validation layer to your logic before you add something to the database  or handle the exception properly and remove invalid models from the context.

Comment: i was searching exactly "remove invalid models from the context." do you have reference to share?

Comment: ` _context.Student.Remove(student);`

Comment: my 'student' object is inside try block .. i can't get it in exception block.

Comment: try moving it outside. I think you're asking more than one question here.